# How to manage visibility of EC2 userdata in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, user-data

The AWS EC2 Dashboard allows users to view/change the userdata for any given EC2 instance via

> Actions -> Instance Settings -> View/Change User Data"

Is there an AWS IAM action that can restrict this feature from users of the Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon EC2 User Data is retrieved via the [`DescribeInstanceAttribute`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceAttribute.html) API call. You can create a **policy to DENY** such permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "NoAttributes",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, there is a risk that denying this permission might have some unintended side-effects because it will also block access to other attributes, too. So, make sure you test it.

It's also worth pointing out that User Data is only executed the **first time the instance boots** ("once per instance-id"). So, even if users have the ability to edit the User Data, it won't actually be executed after the first boot.

Comment: "User Data is only executed the first time the instance boots" is not true. You can add text/cloud-config content type to override how frequently user data is executed in the cloud-init package and a scripts-user block to always execute.

Comment: Correct. The above advice refers to the default configuration for cloud-init on an Amazon-provided AMI. There are actually _lots_ of amazing options for cloud-init. Details available at: [cloud-init Documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)